# I am very noble and loved by many people. What am I?

Tags: riddle

I am very noble.

I am loved by many people

How good were those early days!!

Now,I have almost disappeared from the face of the Earth

Only the Royal can test me, no one else can.

People view me as prestige and honour..

I change every day. Recently, I skyrocketed.

Don't worry, all you have to do is venture a guess as to who am I...

---

HINT : As you guys are having trouble on the Royal part, hint is :

> think chemical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well improving @Michael's answer
you are

> gold

I am very noble.

> The noble was the first English gold coin produced in quantity,also can be reference to Nobel metal(gold is noble metal)

I am loved by many people

> well, who doesn't love gold

How good were those early days!!
Now,I have almost disappeared from the face of the Earth

> maybe referring to increasing consumption of gold and decreasing amount of the gold on earth

Only the Royal can test me, no one else can.
this was my initial guess

> well Royals have the utensils made of gold

after much discussion and with the help of hint this is new guess(thanks @Jasen)

> Aqua regia, also known as 'Royal Water' a very strong acid (nitric acid + hydrochloric acid) it is used to refine gold, and it can also dissolve gold

People view me as prestige and honor..

> gold medal

I change every day. Recently, I skyrocketed.

> gold price changes every day

Comment: You need to work on the Royal part. The answer is correct, yet I won't accept it until u get the Royal part correct.

Comment: @sid are you actually refering to 'Royal Gold' gold mine investers?http://www.royalgold.com/

Comment: Nope, as i hinted, think chemical..

Comment: @sid oh! i think i am closer with this : is it nitric acid( pure compound) which is used to test gold?

Comment: here;s a clue: Aqua regia

Comment: @jasen ooohh! got it got it , 'royal water' a very strong acid, nitric acid + hydrochloric acid, it is used to refine gold.

Comment: at last.. someone got it

Comment: I just read, that it can dissolve gold! This was new for me

Comment: Well done.  +1  Maybe the good early days were supposed to refer to a golden age?

Answer (score 9):

As we've established it is not:

> Gold, money, coin etc.

I think you might be

> Helium

I am very noble.

> Helium is a noble gas

I am loved by many people

> What's not to like about balloons and squeaky voices?

How good were those early days!!

> Helium was one of the first elements in the universe, formed by simple fusion of hydrogen

Now,I have almost disappeared from the face of the Earth

> There is a world shortage of helium

Only the Royal can test me, no one else can.

> Mmm... possibly a reference to excimer compounds of helium

People view me as prestige and honour..

> Mmm... stumped there

I change every day. Recently, I skyrocketed.

> The amount of helium changes every day. The price has increased dramatically.

Don't worry, all you have to do is venture a guess as to Who am I..

Comment: I like this answer. Could the recent skyrocket refer to [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-36651048)

Comment: actually Michael got the answer, yet, his reasonings were not correct. Thus, I couldn't accept his answer. I like your answer though. Some very good fits..+1

Answer (score 5):

> Money? Possibly gold?

Reasoning:

I am very noble.

> Nobel: a former English gold coin first issued in 1351.

I am loved by many people

> Obvious

How good were those early days!!

> Inflation means currency devalues

Now,I have almost disappeared from the face of the Earth

> Most people use credit cards etc. rather than physical money.

Only the Royal can test me, no one else can.

Not sure about this one.

People view me as prestige and honour..

> Qualities associated with the rich

I change every day. Recently, I skyrocketed.

> Relative value of different currencies fluctuates.

Don't worry, all you have to do is venture a guess as to Who am I..

> 'Venture' is a possible clue?

Comment: Royal Mint? maybe...

Comment: @Neon612 "test me" though?

Comment: extremely close, almost the correct answer.. Have to work on your reasonings though.. not what I had in my mind

Comment: @Michael https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_of_the_Pyx The coins are tested to make sure they conform to standards

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems that people are having a hard time with this one.
(Improving on Michael's and smirti's answers)

You are:

> gold

I am very noble.

> The noble was the first English gold coin produced in quantity, also can be reference to Nobel metal (gold is noble metal) [@smirti]

I am loved by many people

> well, who doesn't love gold  [@smirti]

How good were those early days!! Now, I have almost disappeared from the face of the Earth

> maybe referring to increasing consumption of gold and decreasing amount of the gold on earth [@smirti]

Only the Royal can test me, no one else can.

> The [Royal Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Mint#Trial_of_the_Pyx) tests the coins to make sure they are up to standards

People view me as prestige and honor..

> gold medal [@smirti]

I change every day. Recently, I skyrocketed.

> gold price changes every day [@smirti]